# sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor: depth of tree is bigger than specified when max_leaf_nodes != None

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am currently working on a prediction problem, which i tried to solve with a `scikit-learns DecisionTreeRegressor` when i came across the following issue:

> When fitting a tree specifying both parameters `max_depth` and
>   `max_leaf_nodes`, the `depth` of the resulting tree is `max_depth+1`.
>   When fitting a tree specifying only `max_depth`, the resulting tree
>   has the `correct depth`.

Could this be a mistake in the `DecisionTreeRegressor class` or am i missing some common knowledge about regression trees?

I am working on a windows machine, in a python 3.7 jupyter notebook. Sklearn version is 0.20.3.
Actually i came across this working with `RandomForestRegressor`, but found the same issue for `DecisionTreeRegressor`.

I wrote the following simplified example, so you can try yourself. Just uncomment `max_leaf_nodes=10`.

I also visualized the trees using `graphviz`, which actually showed trees of different depth.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

X = np.random.rand(10,4)
y = np.random.rand(10,1)


tree = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth = 2,
                             #max_leaf_nodes = 10 
                             )
tree.fit(X,y)

print(tree.tree_.max_depth)
```

Thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is not documented, if `max_leaf_nodes` is not set, a `DepthFirstTreeBuilder` will be used to fit the underlying tree object; if it is, then a `BestFirstTreeBuilder` will be used; this difference results in trees of different depths being generated.

This is an implementation-specific detail, and not because of the specific characteristics of decision trees.

As an aside, I would note that the maximum number of leaf nodes also constrains the maximum depth.